# How to apply BsonIgnoreExtraElements globally on all classes?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to apply `BsonIgnoreExtraElements` on all my C# class which represent mongo document. So every time I changes something in my document don't get any error.

Let me know how it can be done.

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class ParticipantSurvey : BaseSurvey
{
  public List<ParticipantSurveySection> Sections { get; set; }

  public List<ParticipantSurveyQuestion> G
```